# "no such file or directory" when converting videos to new folder structure

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I am trying to copy a large archive of videos (sitting in subfolders) to a parallel folder structure while converting the videos from mov to mp4 (plus some other tweaks).  This is the command:

```
for f in Users/me/VIDEOARCHIVE/*/*.mov; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "Users/me/CONVERTED/${f%.mov}.mp4"; done
```

<del>However, I get "no such file or directory" for the output file.  I know there are many similar questions on this site, but neither of them was helpful for my scenario.

I also tried creating an empty folder structure beforehand such that it would only have to create the .mp4 file but still I get the same error.</del>

It does work when the (empty) folder structure is already created beforehand. But as soon as there is a folder that is missing I get "no such file or directory".

Is there a way to tell it to create parent folders if it needs to so that it can place files into them?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with `set -x` beforehand or `echo "Users/me/CONVERTED/${f%.mov}.mp4"` inside the loop? This should give you some clue.

Comment: ffmpeg may have issues with long filenames or paths, or those with spaces. Try a shorter one.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you, I had placed the parallel folder structure in the wrong place ... my bad :P  But I'm still wondering why does `ffmpeg` not create the folders if it needs to (I've reworded my question accordingly).

Comment: Looks like `ffmpeg` won't create directories when outputting. In your `do` loop before your `ffmpeg` call, get the path of the directory that will contain the output file, and `mkdir -p` it. Optionally check for existence before trying to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell it to create parent folders if it needs to so that it can place files into them?

ffmpeg? No. It won't create folders on its own. Actually, very few programs do this.

Some suggestions:

- You should create the folder beforehand.
- You need to use the basename of the file, as `$f` already contains the full file path.
- You should use recursive globbing for your video archive (`**/*`) to traverse all directories.

Putting that together:

```bsh
# enable recursive globbing
shopt -s globstar
# create the directory if necessary
dir="/Users/me/CONVERTED/"
mkdir -p "$dir"
# iterate over all files
for f in /Users/me/VIDEOARCHIVE/**/*.mov; do
    # get the file's basename
    fname="$(basename "$f")"
    # run the command, replacing the file extension
    ffmpeg -i "$f" "$dir/${fname%.mov}.mp4"
done
```

Comment: Eh, sorry, I just took that from the user's loop without noticing that even if ffmpeg was able to create output folders, the code is wrong. Let me fix that.